# Duplicate WP theme with different configuration

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am using Salient (from themeforest) theme on my wordpress website. I would like to duplicate my theme and modify the second one to be more mobile friendly. It's easy to duplicate it, but I just can't manage to modify one theme without affecting the other. The 2 themes are located in folders with different names, I also modified the name of the 2nd theme in style.css, so in Appearence>Themes they have different names, but it doesn't help me much. I modify my second theme and then activate the 1st one which is just like the one I modified. Maybe it's a database issue, or I don't know, I am noob in WP. All I want is 2 themes (well, the same one 2 times) but with different configs. Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks in advance!
Buzas.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a child theme to do this properly. However, if I look at what you want to achieve, you will probably succeed by adding the custom css plugin and adding some extra css rules.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Comment: Child theme is not working, the theme has one, but same issue. Will try the custom css plugin :) Ty!

Answer (score 0):

I think the theme itself should have custom CSS editor, as far as I have worked with Themeforest themes, they all had it. You should check among its options.

Comment: Of course it has, I thought the other suggestion is different, it's still not solved :(